# Calculate direction of coordinates

Tags: c#

I wanted conditions that could determine which direction (north, south, east, west, northwest, northeast, southeast, southwest) the player is following, what I got was just north, south, east and west, as shown in the code below:

```
var playerX = player.x, playerY = player.y;

var destX = 8, destY = -15;

    if (playerX < destX) {
      playerX += 0.5; // east
    } else if (playerX > destX) {
      playerX -= 0.5; // west
    } else {
      playerX = destX; // maintains direction
    }
    if (playerY < destY) {
      playerY += 0.5; // north
    } else if (playerY > destY) {
      playerY -= 0.5; // south
    } else {
      playerY = destY; //maintains direction
    }
```

---

**image example:**
[image]

Comment: What are `destX` and `destY`, `playerX` and `player`, and `player.x` and `player.y`? What do they represent? Why do you hardcode `0.5`, what is this value representing?

Comment: what do you need exactly ! what is your game engine? can you share picture that show your problem?

Comment: I'm a bit confused. It looks like this code already computes movement correctly for northwest, northeast, etc. like you say you want. To take an example, if `playerX < destX` and `playerY < destY` then the player will move positively in both the x and y axes (ie. northeast). Have I misunderstood your code or the question you're asking?

Comment: Currently I have 4 directions (north, south, east and west), and I need to work like 4 others (northwest, northeast, southeast, southwest). TOTALLY 8 DIRECTIONS, BUT I JUST HAVE 4!

I updated the post with the improved code, and also a representative image.

Comment: I'm using three.js, but I do not think it matters much. Since this is a basic Cartesian problem, but I'm not in the mood. I'M SORRY, I'M USING A TRANSLATOR, I'M A BRAZILIAN.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this code:

```
var lastX, lastY;
function geraDirecao(player) {
    var playerX = player.position.x,
        playerY = player.position.y;


    if(playerX < lastX) {
        if (playerY < lastY) {
            // top left 
        } else if (playerY == lastY) {
             // left
        } else { // playerY > lastY
            // bottom left
        }
    } else
    if (playerX == lastX) {
        if (playerY < lastY) {
            // top
        } else if (playerY == lastY) {
            // Not allowed
        } else { // playerY > lastY
            // bottom
        }
    } else { // playerX > lastX
        if (playerY < lastY) {
            // top right
        } else if (playerY == lastY) {
            // right
        } else {// playerY > lastY
            // bottom right
        }
    }

    lastX = playerX;
    lastY = playerY;
}
```

Comment: [You may also find this answer helpful for reducing the amount of branching to a simple table lookup instead](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/131336/39518). Since you're using floats for positions, you'd need to add a little clamping/rounding first.

Answer (score 1):

[image: king,bishop,rook]

Imagine your player is a chess piece on a chessboard then look at the  picture how every chess piece are moving and which field are valid fields for each piece, How ever your problem is more look like a Queen on a chess board because can move on every direction and you can adapt this algorithm to your player.
you need array to loop through every row and column.

Here is the code for how a Queen move on a chessboard.

```
 public class Queen extends Chesspiece {

    protected Queen(char color, char name) { 
        super(color, name);
    }

    @Override 
    public void markReachableFields() { 
        char rw = row;
        byte col = column;

        for (char i = 'a'; i <='h'; i++) {
            rw = (char)i;       
            if ((rw >= 'a' && rw <= 'h') && (col >= 1 && col <= 8)
                    &&Chessboard.this.isValidField(rw, col)){
                int r = rw - FIRST_ROW;
                int c = col - FIRST_COLUMN;
                Chessboard.this.fields[r][c].mark();
            }
        }
        col = column;
        rw = row;
        for (byte j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
            col = (byte)j;
            if ((rw >= 'a' && rw <= 'h') && (col >= 1 && col <= 8)
                    &&Chessboard.this.isValidField(rw, col)){
                int r = rw - FIRST_ROW;
                int c = col - FIRST_COLUMN;
                Chessboard.this.fields[r][c].mark();
            }
        }
        rw = row;
        col = column;
        for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
            rw = (char)(rw - 1);
            col = (byte)(col + 1);

            if ((rw >= 'a' && rw <= 'h') && (col >= 1 && col <= 8)
                    &&Chessboard.this.isValidField(rw, col)){
                int r = rw - FIRST_ROW;
                int c = col - FIRST_COLUMN;
                Chessboard.this.fields[r][c].mark();
            }
        }
        rw = row;
        col = column;

        for (int i = 1; i <= 8; i++) {
            rw = (char)(rw + 1);
            col = (byte)(col + 1);
            if ((rw >= 'a' && rw <= 'h') && (col >= 1 && col <= 8)
                    &&Chessboard.this.isValidField(rw, col)){
                int r = rw - FIRST_ROW;
                int c = col - FIRST_COLUMN;
                Chessboard.this.fields[r][c].mark();
            }
        }
         rw = row;
         col = column;

        for (int i = 1; i <= 8; i++) {
            rw = (char)(rw + 1);
            col = (byte)(col - 1);
            if ((rw >= 'a' && rw <= 'h') && (col >= 1 && col <= 8)
                    &&Chessboard.this.isValidField(rw, col)){
                int r = rw - FIRST_ROW;
                int c = col - FIRST_COLUMN;
                Chessboard.this.fields[r][c].mark();
            }
        }

         rw = row;
         col = column;
        for (int i = 1; i <= 8; i++) {
            rw = (char)(rw - 1);
            col = (byte)(col - 1);
            if ((rw >= 'a' && rw <= 'h') && (col >= 1 && col <= 8)
                    &&Chessboard.this.isValidField(rw, col)){
                int r = rw - FIRST_ROW;
                int c = col - FIRST_COLUMN;
                Chessboard.this.fields[r][c].mark();

            }
        }
    }
    @Override 
    public void unmarkReachableFields() {
        char rw = row;
        byte col = column;

        for (char i = 'a'; i <='h'; i++) {
            rw = (char)i;       
            if ((rw >= 'a' && rw <= 'h') && (col >= 1 && col <= 8)
                    &&Chessboard.this.isValidField(rw, col)){
                int r = rw - FIRST_ROW;
                int c = col - FIRST_COLUMN;
                Chessboard.this.fields[r][c].unmark();
            }
        }
        col = column;
        rw = row;
        for (byte j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
            col = (byte)j;
            if ((rw >= 'a' && rw <= 'h') && (col >= 1 && col <= 8)
                    &&Chessboard.this.isValidField(rw, col)){
                int r = rw - FIRST_ROW;
                int c = col - FIRST_COLUMN;
                Chessboard.this.fields[r][c].unmark();
            }
        }
        rw = row;
        col = column;
        for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
            rw = (char)(rw - 1);
            col = (byte)(col + 1);

            if ((rw >= 'a' && rw <= 'h') && (col >= 1 && col <= 8)
                    &&Chessboard.this.isValidField(rw, col)){
                int r = rw - FIRST_ROW;
                int c = col - FIRST_COLUMN;
                Chessboard.this.fields[r][c].unmark();
            }
        }
        rw = row;
        col = column;

        for (int i = 1; i <= 8; i++) {
            rw = (char)(rw + 1);
            col = (byte)(col + 1);
            if ((rw >= 'a' && rw <= 'h') && (col >= 1 && col <= 8)
                    &&Chessboard.this.isValidField(rw, col)){
                int r = rw - FIRST_ROW;
                int c = col - FIRST_COLUMN;
                Chessboard.this.fields[r][c].unmark();
            }
        }
         rw = row;
         col = column;

        for (int i = 1; i <= 8; i++) {
            rw = (char)(rw + 1);
            col = (byte)(col - 1);
            if ((rw >= 'a' && rw <= 'h') && (col >= 1 && col <= 8)
                    &&Chessboard.this.isValidField(rw, col)){
                int r = rw - FIRST_ROW;
                int c = col - FIRST_COLUMN;
                Chessboard.this.fields[r][c].unmark();
            }
        }

         rw = row;
         col = column;
        for (int i = 1; i <= 8; i++) {
            rw = (char)(rw - 1);
            col = (byte)(col - 1);
            if ((rw >= 'a' && rw <= 'h') && (col >= 1 && col <= 8)
                    &&Chessboard.this.isValidField(rw, col)){
                int r = rw - FIRST_ROW;
                int c = col - FIRST_COLUMN;
                Chessboard.this.fields[r][c].unmark();

            }
        }
    }
 }
```